# I am using an EfficientDet-D0 object detection model i.e, a frozen model .pb for the TFTRT API to manage the inference on TensorRT

Tags: python, tensorflow

Get this as error:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1574, in _call_impl
args.append(kwargs.pop(compat.as_str(keyword)))
KeyError: 'global_step'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection.py", line 416, in <module>
    optimize_offline=args.optimize_offline)
  File "object_detection.py", line 124, in get_graph_func
    converter.build(input_fn=partial(input_fn, data_dir, 1))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/compiler/tensorrt/trt_convert.py", line 1040, in build
    self._converted_func(*map(ops.convert_to_tensor, inp))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1551, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py", line 1583, in _call_impl
    list(set(self._arg_keywords) - set(specified_keywords))))
TypeError: Expected argument names ['image_arrays', 'global_step'] but got values for ['image_arrays']. Missing: ['global_step'].
```

I could see that there is a missing parameter. Any insight to fix it?